# How to define a variable in external config file and use it in app.module

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular5, angular-aot

In Ionic 3 with Angular 5 I am trying to define all my external API keys inside an `app.config.ts` file.

I must declare a class otherwise I get an AOT error raised by ngc.

Here is my app.config.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
  public ONESIGNAL_API_KEY: string;
  public FIREBASE_CONFIG: any;
  public MIXPANEL_TOKEN: string;

  constructor() {
    this.ONESIGNAL_API_KEY = 'myoskey';
    this.FIREBASE_CONFIG = {
      apiKey: "myfbkey",
      authDomain: "myfbdomain
      };
    this.MIXPANEL_TOKEN = 'mymptoken';
  }
}
```

I can inject it in constructors of other classes but firebase must be initialize in `app.module.ts`. So I tried to do the following
// Config

```
import {AppConfig} from './app-config';
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      backButtonText: '',
      tabsHideOnSubPages: true,
      //scrollAssist: true,
      //autoFocusAssist: true
    }),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    IonicImageLoader.forRoot(),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(AppConfig.FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    ....
```

Unfortunately I get the following error
`Property 'FIREBASE_CONFIG' does not exist on type 'typeof AppConfig'.`

How can declare `FIREBASE_CONFIG` within this `app.config` file and directly use it in `app.module`?

I tried to directly initialize the variable before the constructor like this, but same result

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
  public ONESIGNAL_API_KEY: string;
  public FIREBASE_CONFIG: any = {
      apiKey: "myfbkey",
      authDomain: "myfbdomain
      };
  public MIXPANEL_TOKEN: string;

  constructor() {
    this.ONESIGNAL_API_KEY = 'myoskey';
    this.MIXPANEL_TOKEN = 'mymptoken';
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you could use an enum :

```
export enum AppConfig {
    ONESIGNAL_API_KEY = 'myoskey',
    MIXPANEL_TOKEN = 'mymptoken'
}

export const FIREBASE_CONFIG = {
    apiKey : "myfbkey",
    authDomain : "myfbdomain"
}
```

and you use it as you did :

```
import {AppConfig ,FIREBASE_CONFIG  } from './config';
...
imports: [
    //...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG)
```

Note : you get that error because you're trying to access `AppConfig.FIREBASE_CONFIG` and `FIREBASE_CONFIG` is a non static property of `AppConfig` class.

Comment: I get the following error regarding the FIREBASE_CONFIG with your method: `Computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members.`

Comment: As soon as I use something else than a class I get the following error (since Angular 5 I think) : `Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve ./app-config.ts relative to
            /Users/me/myproj/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol
            AppModule in /Users/me/myproj/src/app/app.module.ts,
            resolving symbol AppModule in
            /Users/me/myproj/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol
            AppModule in /Users/me/myproj/src/app/app.module.ts

Error: The Angular AoT build failed.`